# TSQL Loop through two queries to insert into another table

Tags: sql-server, linq, t-sql

For Example, say I have two tables

```
Product(id, name)
Company(id, name)
```

I want to loop through every product and every company in order to build a related table(already built so I would use an insert here).

```
CompanyProduct(companyId, productId)
```

I have never done a loop with TSQL. I know easily how to do this with LINQ, but TSQL should be faster for the amount of records I want to do this with.An

Seeing as I am looking at having to build upwards of 80,000 - 150,000 new records every time this is used what is the most efficient way I could go about this? Thanks for your help

Comment: Why do you need a loop?  You can SELECT from your source tables and INSERT to your target table.

Comment: what do you mean with "x  new records every time this is used" ?

Comment: It will create a lot of records, but it takes a long time using linq. It literally took over 8 hours.

Comment: If it is always a complete list, why not make CompanyProduct a View instead?  `Create view CompanyProduct AS SELECT c.id as companyId,p.id as productId FROM Company c CROSS JOIN Product p`, then it will always be up to date.  Or create insert triggers on company/product to insert into the CompanyProduct table?

Comment: @TaylorMitchell TSQL is a declarative language where you ask the system what you want and the system determines which is the best way to find the answer to your question (how) and returns it to you. When dealing with rdbms you should think in terms of Sets and operations between those sets (where sql servers excels in performance) rather than imperative constructs such as loops (which are performance killers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want a combination of every Product and Company, you are looking for a CROSS JOIN, like this:

```
INSERT INTO CompanyProduct
SELECT P.id, C.id FROM Product as P CROSS JOIN Company AS C;
```

This will be very fast.

Hope that helps,

Ash